# An interpretation for $n\prod_{p\vert n}(1-3/p)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

As well-known, $n\prod_{p\vert n}(1-1/p)$ (where the product is over all prime divisors of a natural integer $n$) is the number of classes modulo $n$ which are invertible modulo $n$.

Similarly, $n\prod_{p\vert n}(1-2/p)$ counts the number (up to equivalence 
modulo affine transformations of $\mathbb Z^2$) of triangles of area $n/2$
with integral vertices $A,B,C$ (labelled in order to destroy automorphisms
and inducing the orientation of the plane)
and no other integral points on the boundary.
(Proof: Up to affine transformations, one can assume $A=(0,0),B=(0,1)$
and $C=(n,i)$ with $i\in\{0,n-1\}$ such that $n$ is coprime with $i$ and $i-1$.
If $n$ is a prime power $p^a$ this leaves $p^a-2p^{a-1}$ possibilities and the 
general case follows from the Chinese remainder Theorem.)

Is there an interesting interpretation for $n\prod_{p\vert n}(1-3/p)$? (One has perhaps to restrict
the formula to odd natural integers.)

By interesting I mean an interpretation different from the obvious one:
For $n\geq 3$ odd, $n\prod_{p\vert n}(1-3/p)$ counts the number of classes $i$ modulo $n$
such that $i,i+1$ and $i+2$ are all coprime with $n$.

Comment: Something like simplices of volume $n/6$ with integral vertices and no other integral points on the boundary? i.e., $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(0,1,0)$, $C=(0,0,2)$, and $D=(n,n,i)$ or something like that?

Comment: @Greg Martin: Yes something like that would be nice except that your simplex has (at least) the point $(0,0,1)=(A+C)/2$ on the boundary.
(I guess you meant $D=(n,i,i)$ for the coordinates of $D$?)